# PHP readfile imprime archivo en pantalla

Tags: php, wordpress, descarga

Estoy tratando de descargar un archivo desde el servidor en PHP, estoy trabajando con Wordpress, este es mi código

```
<?php
    // Genera la descarga del convenio colectivo de trabajo

    $dirBase = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-content/themes/accelerate/convenioColectivo/convenio_colectivo";

    // Veo si es un .doc, un .docx o un .pdf
    if (file_exists($dirBase . ".doc")) {
        $ext = ".doc";
        $ctype = "application/msword";
    } else {
        if (file_exists($dirBase . ".docx")) {
            $ext = ".docx";
            $ctype = "application/msword";
        } else {
            if (file_exists($dirBase . ".pdf")) {
                $ext = ".pdf";
                $ctype = "application/pdf";
            } else 
                exit();
        }
    }

    $archivo = $dirBase . $ext;

    header("Pragma: public"); 
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: " . $ctype); // Pongo el tipo de informacion correspondiente
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=convenio_colectivo" . $ext ); // Que se descargue con el nombre convenio_colectivo + extension correspondiente siempre
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize($archivo)); // Traiga solo lo que pesa el archivo
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $archivo );

?>
```

**En el Localhost funciona perfecto y se descarga sin problemas**. Pero cuando lo hosteo ocurre esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me está imprimiendo en pantalla en vez de descargarse ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como podría solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí encontré la solución. Al parecer el código que agrega Wordpress para los templates hacía que no funcione correctamente la descarga. Simplemente lo puse debajo de mi código de descarga.

**Antes:**

```
 <?php
    /*
    Template Name: Convenio Colectivo
    */ 
    /**
     * Theme Page Section for our theme.
     *
     * @package ThemeGrill
     * @subpackage Accelerate
     * @since Accelerate 1.0
     */
    ?>

<?php
    // Genera la descarga del convenio colectivo de trabajo.

    $dirBase = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/accelerate/convenioColectivo/convenio_colectivo";

    // Veo si es un .doc, un .docx o un .pdf
    if (file_exists($dirBase . ".doc")) {
        $ext = ".doc";
        $ctype = "application/msword";
    } else {
        if (file_exists($dirBase . ".docx")) {
            $ext = ".docx";
            $ctype = "application/msword";
        } else {
            if (file_exists($dirBase . ".pdf")) {
                $ext = ".pdf";
                $ctype = "application/pdf";
            } else 
                exit();
        }
    }

    $archivo = $dirBase . $ext;

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: " . $ctype); // Pongo el tipo de informacion correspondiente
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=convenio_colectivo" . $ext ); // Que se descargue con el nombre convenio_colectivo + extension correspondiente siempre
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize($archivo)); // Traiga solo lo que pesa el archivo
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $archivo );
?>
```

**Después:**

```
<?php
    // Genera la descarga del convenio colectivo de trabajo.
    // Se pone el otro codigo abajo para que en internet funcione correctamente la descarga

    $dirBase = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/accelerate/convenioColectivo/convenio_colectivo";

    // Veo si es un .doc, un .docx o un .pdf
    if (file_exists($dirBase . ".doc")) {
        $ext = ".doc";
        $ctype = "application/msword";
    } else {
        if (file_exists($dirBase . ".docx")) {
            $ext = ".docx";
            $ctype = "application/msword";
        } else {
            if (file_exists($dirBase . ".pdf")) {
                $ext = ".pdf";
                $ctype = "application/pdf";
            } else 
                exit();
        }
    }

    $archivo = $dirBase . $ext;

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: " . $ctype); // Pongo el tipo de informacion correspondiente
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=convenio_colectivo" . $ext ); // Que se descargue con el nombre convenio_colectivo + extension correspondiente siempre
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize($archivo)); // Traiga solo lo que pesa el archivo
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $archivo );
?>

<?php
  /*
  Template Name: Convenio Colectivo
  */ 
  /**
   * Theme Page Section for our theme.
   *
   * @package ThemeGrill
   * @subpackage Accelerate
   * @since Accelerate 1.0
   */
 ?>
```

Comment: Yo creo que en realidad el error es el espacio entre ambos códigos.
Prueba borrar esto:
    ?>
    
    <?php

Comment: Actualmente está así y me funciona. Cualquier caso que falle probaré lo que decís. Gracias por responder! Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

La primera de la llamadas a header() debe ser:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, después pruebo, pero si tengo un archivo.doc o .docx no generaría problemas?